# How to deploy node.js application in AWS

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, sails.js

When i tried deploying my new node.js application in AWS, iam getting an error

```
Failed to find package.json. Node.js may have issues starting. Verify package.json is valid or place code in a file named server.js or app.js.
```

I have already validated my package.json and it is showing true.

My package.json file is as below:

```
{
"name": "sgcp",
"private": true,
"version": "0.0.0",
"description": "a Sails application",
"dependencies": {
    "sails": "0.9.7",
    "nodemailer": "~0.6.1",
    "grunt": "0.4.1",
    "sails-disk": "~0.9.0",
    "ejs": "0.8.4",
    "optimist": "0.3.4",
    "sails-mongo": "~0.9.7"
},
"scripts": {
    "start": "node app.js",
    "debug": "node debug app.js"
},
"main": "app.js",
"repository": "git@github.com:xteam/xcp.git",
"author": "sg",
"license": "Proprietory",
"engines": {
    "node": "0.10.x"
}
}
```

Any help is appreciated. Thanks a lot.

Comment: Do you have SSH access to the Amazon instance? Is there a specific issue checking or are you just generally not sure how to check?

Comment: I tried deploying a new application . I got an error            Failed to find package.json. Node.js may have issues starting. Verify package.json is valid or place code in a file named server.js or app.js. What could be the reason ? I tried validating with package.json validator which showed it is valid.

Comment: How are you attempting to start the application? What is the exact error? Can you perhaps update your question with all pertinent information.

Comment: @Mahahari, you need to give us a little more info on what you did before you go this error.
How are you deploying to AWS?
When does this error occur?

Comment: did you find the root cause?

Comment: ya , found the root cause. It was the problem with database. Due to that , it didnt deploy properly

Answer (score 9):

When uploading to AWS though a zip folder, I found this thread on AWS to be useful: https://forums.aws.amazon.com/thread.jspa?threadID=130140&tstart=0

Basically make sure that you zip all the contents inside your project and not the folder that contains your project. The zip file should contain app.js/server.js and package.json directly and not a folder which holds these files.

Answer (score 3):

While deploying `.zip` file (Nodejs application) in to AWS Elastic Beanstalck, zip file should not have any parent folder on top of index.js Or package.json.
We need to select all the files in the project folder folder, then zip it as shown in below screenshot. 
Then upload the Nodejs(zip file) project in AWS Elastic Beanstalck. 
[image]